# Mass assignment of model rules

Tags: php, yii

I want to know if there is a easy way to mass assign a new set of rules for a model.

The use case is that I could have a validator rule which contains a set of sub rules for a specific model. I want to dynamically load that model, assign its attributes (both of which I know how to do) and then mass assign the set of rules. The rules will look like:

```
'rules' => array(
    array('road', 'string'),
    array('town', 'string'),
    array('county', 'string'),
    array('post_code', 'string'),
    array('telephone', 'integer')
)
```

I know I can do this by picking out the classes individually and building up the validators manually but is there any easy way to just tell a Yii model to reload the validators with this specification?

Comment: use scenarios? http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/ http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21730-scenario-and-find-or-findall/

Comment: @ImreL How? I am not sure how that helps, I am looking to mass assign rules to a model not contain certain rules to a scenario

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by mass assigning. Is it about assigning rules to a set (array) of models or is it about assigning multiple rules to one model with one assignment? No yii specific featrures exist for former (you still have to loop over each model or use sublcassing etc.). For last one using scenarios is one of many options depending of your needs

Comment: @ImreL Basically imagine I have a validator that runs on an array within a model. This array is supported by a validation rule which as one of its properties has the `rules` definition you see above. I have a standard class called `EModel` which I instantiate and apply the set of defined rules within my validation rule that was defined previously in the parent model. Each iteration of the parent models array resets the attributes of the EModel and revalidates. What I need to do is apply a set of rules to the empty model according to that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out the answer in the end through a issue ( https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/987#issuecomment-8886072 ) on Github whereby it was mentioned to look at the `CModel` `validatorList`. After browsing this source code for a while I came up with the following piece of code, mostly ripped from `CModel` itself:

```
$c=new EMongoModel();
foreach($this->rules as $rule){
    if(isset($rule[0],$rule[1]))  // attributes, validator name
        $c->validatorList->add->add(CValidator::createValidator($rule[1],$this,$rule[0],array_slice($rule,2)));
    else
        throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} has an invalid validation rule. The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name.',
                    array('{class}'=>get_class($this))));
}
```

Now this allows me to take a list of array elements that look like validation rules for a model and on the spot actually make them into validation rules for the model.